# Detect (from a webpage) what browsers are installed?

Tags: windows, browser

I suspect the answer is NO b/c I doubt one browser has access to info about other browsers. But I wanted to verify.

Is there anyway for a website to detect what other browsers are installed (on a Windows computer)?

Comment: No. What a massive security hole that would be - allowing a web page to iterate what you've got installed on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only get info on the web browser they are using.